# Cuál es la dimensión adecuada para una imagen de background en react native?

Tags: react-native

Estoy realizando una aplicación en react native, y quiero agregar una imagen de background y splash. Cuál debería ser el tamaño y formato? Tengo entendido que en Android se manejan así las dimensiones:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Cómo debo manejarlas en react native? anexo que la aplicación móvil espera correr en iOS y Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar un generador automático para esos assets. A continuación te recomiendo algunas opciones:

1. https://apetools.webprofusion.com/#/
2. https://itnext.io/pwa-splash-screen-and-icon-generator-a74ebb8a130

   - https://github.com/onderceylan/pwa-asset-generator
3. https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html
4. http://nsimage.brosteins.com/
5. https://makeappicon.com/

Una vez que tengas los assets adecuados también te recomiendo usar la siguiente librería para el splash: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/184574)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. La parte esencial de la respuesta es que use un generador automático. Doy 5 ejemplos justo con la misma idea de que si alguno deja de funcionar se tenga una referencia de otros.